# There is / are; Questions > Answers; is > are ; are >is

Tags: questions, there-is

If someone asks me **Are there any phones in the room?** Can I answer   **yes there is / no there isn't**  to possible indicate .... let's say that there's just one phone or none or for any other reason

If someone asks me **Is there a phone in the room?** Can I answer **yes there are / no there aren't** (same idea as the first example)

Comment: If somebody asks you *"are there any phones in the room"*, and there is exactly one, you can say *yes, there is one.* If there aren't any, you should say *no, there aren't*.

Comment: And, I think if they asked _"is there a phone in this room"_, you could reply, _"yes, there are two..."_

Comment: Your question actually involves two major issues: (1) verb agreement in an existential construction, (2) response to a question. Answer for #1, there is no need for verb agreement in an existential construction--even though grade schools and pop-grammarians push bogus "rules" at you. (The rule is: Trust your ear.) For #2, often a person will respond to a question by sorta echoing part of the question back; so if the questioner began the question with *"Are there"*, the responder might begin the response with *"(Yes/no) there are"*; and the same with *"There is"*--but it's up to the responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets clearer if you write out the full response:

> **Are there any *phones in the room*?**
>   Yes there is *phones in the room*.
>   No there isn't *phones in the room*.

So, if you answer strictly yes/no to the asker's question, you can now see that replying with *"Yes there is..."* to an *"Are there any..."* question is grammatically incorrect. The same goes for *"Is there any..."* questions; the pluralization in the response should match the pluralization in the question.

**However,** you *can* modify your reply if you want to imply something, such as in this case, how many phones can be found:

> **Are there any *phones in the room*?**
>   Yes there is [*a phone in the room*].
>   Yes there are [*several phones in the room*].
>   No there aren't [*any phones in the room*].

Comment: Why the downvote? Is the answer incorrect in any way?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by user **F.E.** [in the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161962/there-is-are-questions-answers-is-are-are-is#comment338598_161962):

> Your question actually involves two major issues:
>
> (1) verb agreement in an existential construction,
>
> (2) response to a question. Answer for #1, there is no need for verb
>   agreement in an existential construction--even though grade schools
>   and pop-grammarians push bogus "rules" at you. (The rule is: Trust
>   your ear.)
>
> For #2, often a person will respond to a question by sorta echoing
>   part of the question back; so if the questioner began the question
>   with "*Are there*", the responder might begin the response with
>   "(*Yes/no*) *there are*"; and the same with "*There is*"--but it's up
>   to the responder.